# Read data from postgres DB in every 1 hour time interval in pyspark

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, batch-processing

I want to read data from postgres db of 1 hour time interval, I want the process to run every one hour. How can I do that? I have attached my code snippet. I am unable to use readstream for jdbc option.

```
df = spark.read \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", URL) \
.option("dbtable", "tagpool_with_tag_raw") \
.option("user", "tsdbadmin") \
.option("password", "cgqu5qss2zy3i1") \
.option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
.load()

# Getting the current date and time
dt = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)
utc_time = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
utc_timestamp = utc_time.timestamp()
epoch = round(utc_timestamp / 60) * 60
# epoch = epoch+3600
print("epoch ", epoch)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("tagpool_with_tag_raw")
x = spark.sql("""select *  from tagpool_with_tag_raw""")
x.show()
query = spark.sql("select *  from tagpool_with_tag_raw WHERE input_time = " + str(epoch))  # .format()

    # query = spark.sql("select CAST(input_time AS bigint), CAST(orig_time AS bigint) ,  from tagpool_with_tag_raw WHERE input_time = "+ epoch) #.format()
query.show()
# df.selectExpr(("SELECT * FROM public.tagpool_raw WHERE input_time<= %s".format(epoch)))
df.printSchema()

query.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", URL) \
    .option("dbtable", "tagpool_tag_raw") \
    .option("user", USER) \
    .option("password", PW) \
    .option("driver", DRIVER).save()
```

Comment: Where your code is running? Databricks, on-premises, etc.?

Comment: on-premise         @Kafels

Comment: In this case check in your enterprise to use a tool as scheduler, Apache Airflow, Oozie, etc, but definitely don't put this scheduler inside your code.

Comment: @Kafels thanks, I used Apache airflow, Its works as expected however i am facing issue of  writing duplicate records

Comment: Usually to perform incremental loads it's necessary to have a `watermark` column and perform queries using left bound and right bound concept. Feel free to [create another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) explaining what you're doing and providing some data to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Readstream are not for jdbc , As jdbc is a batch operation, You will have to create a process just like what you have did and use schedulers like AutoSys or oozie or whatever your enterprise as to run every hour.